# Como aplicar um delay na propriedade display do CSS em uma mudança de none para flex sem JavaScript?

Tags: css, css3

Como faço para que a propriedade display do CSS mude de none para flex com um delay de 1s sem usar JavaScript para isso?

Tenho o seguinte código:

```
#botao-painel:checked ~ .painel {
    display: flex;
    height: 100%;
    left: 0;
   top: 0;
   width: 100%;
}
.painel {
    align-items: center;
    background-color: RGBA(0,0,0,0.85);
    display: none;
    height: 0;
    justify-content: center;
    left: 50%;
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    transition: all 1000ms ease 2000ms;
        -webkit-transition: all 1000ms ease 2000ms;
    width: 0;
    z-index: 500;
}
.painel > div {
    align-items: center;
    background-color: RGB(255,255,255);
    display: flex;
    height: 75%;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 46%;
}
```

O problema é que quando faço o clique no botão ele aplica as propriedades em .painel mas o delay e nem a animação são usadas, simplesmente tudo aparece de uma vez.

Alguém tem alguma dica para me dar de como solucionar isso sem usar JavaScript, apenas com CSS?

Comment: Você quer fazer a transição da propriedade `display`, é isso?

Comment: Não, quero que a transição de tamanho comece depois que o display tenha sido mudado para flex.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O problema é que o display não funciona com transição, logo ao checar o elemento será aplicado imediatamente o display flex.

Um contorno para isso é usar a propriedade `visibility` de `hidden` para `visible`, deixando o elemento sempre com `display: flex`. Já que ele é um elemento `fixed`, não irá interferir no layout em relação aos outros elementos.

A propriedade para aplicar o delay é o [transition-delay](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transition-delay).

Veja no código abaixo o que foi removido, adicionado e alterado.

```css
#botao-painel:checked ~ .painel {
   visibility: visible; /* adicionado */
    /*display: flex; removido */
    height: 100%;
    left: 0;
   top: 0;
   width: 100%;
}
.painel {
    align-items: center;
    background-color: RGBA(0,0,0,0.85);
    visibility: hidden; /* adicionado */
    /*display: none;*/
    display: flex; /* alterado */
    height: 0;
    justify-content: center;
    left: 50%;
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    transition: all 1000ms ease 2000ms;
        -webkit-transition: all 1000ms ease 2000ms;
    width: 0;
    z-index: 500;
    -webkit-transition-delay: 5s; /* adicionado */
    transition-delay: 1s; /* adicionado 1 segundo */
}
.painel > div {
    align-items: center;
    background-color: RGB(255,255,255);
    display: flex;
    height: 75%;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 46%;
}
```

```html
<div>
   <input id="botao-painel" type="checkbox"> Marque e aguarde 1 segundo
   <div class="painel">
      <div>
         Painel
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Usar `opacity` 0 e 1 também funciona né?

Comment: Acredito que sim tb.